# Frequent random failures (Service discovery failed) in createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord

Tags: android, bluetooth, rfcomm

I am attempting to establish an insecure Bluetooth socket connection between two Android devices. I control the software on both ends. One end uses `listenUsingInsecureRfcommWithServiceRecord` to listen for a connection, the other end uses `createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord` to connect. This works. **Sometimes.**

The "sometimes" is my problem. In about 20% of the attempts, it fails and throws the following exception:

```
java.io.IOException: Service discovery failed
    at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket$SdpHelper.doSdp(BluetoothSocket.java:403)
    at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.connect(BluetoothSocket.java:213)
    at com.example.bluetoothpoke.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:34)
```

Both devices are awake with screen on. The distance between the devices is around 1m (10 cm and 3m don't make a difference). Neither device is performing discovery. Both devices are discoverable (making both non-discoverable doesn't change anything, either).

Do I have to assume it is normal because of the wireless interface and just try again on failure, or is there something I can do? Shouldn't it work more reliably given that I am at a very comfortable distance?

Note: I found lots of similar questions, but the ones I found are either about "doesn't work at all", connecting to a non-Android device, or both.

Comment: 20% connection failure is not normal .. Its too high (Unless the bluetooth hardware is of very bad quality) Can you port the logcat bluetooth output from android to see what is causing the failure

Comment: `D/BluetoothService(280): Cleaning up failed UUID channel lookup: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx` (the X-ed out values being the target device bluetooth address and the service UUID) is the only thing I see that is different from successful connections. Not very helpful.

Comment: hmm ..cant say much from this snippet

Comment: Hey I have this same issue. Did you find any solution?